# Gtk+ 3 (C) vs gtkmm 3 (CPP) Speed issue with ListStore->append()

Tags: c++, treeview, gtk3, gtkmm

Below are two functionally identical procedures.  Given the exact same data set, the Gtk+3 procedure written in C runs in 0.03 seconds.  The gtkmm 3 procedure written in C++ runs in 30 seconds.  Gtk+ uses "GtkListStore *store" and gtkmm uses "Glib::RefPtrGtk::ListStore  m_refListStore;".

So, the question is, is gtkmm just plain slower by literally 1000 times?  Or, have I missed something in declaring the gtkmm ListStore?  Thank you for any input.

### Gtk+ 3 in C

GtkListStore  *store;

```
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)))
{
    /* Append a row and fill in some data */
    gtk_list_store_append (store, &iter);
    gtk_list_store_set (store, &iter,
                        DIRECTORY_NAME, row[1],
                        FILE_NAME, row[3],
                        EXTENTION, row[5],
                        FILE_SIZE, row[6],
                        FILE_DATE, row[7],
                        -1);
}
```

### gtkmm 3 in CPP

Glib::RefPtrGtk::ListStore  m_refListStore;

```
while ((mysql_row = mysql_fetch_row(res)))
{
    /* Append a row and fill in some data */
    Gtk::ListStore::Row row = *(m_refListStore->append());
    row[m_Columns.m_directory_name] = mysql_row[1];
    row[m_Columns.m_file_name]      = mysql_row[3];
    row[m_Columns.m_file_extention] = mysql_row[5];
    row[m_Columns.m_file_size]      = mysql_row[6];
    row[m_Columns.m_file_date]      = mysql_row[7];
}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal and reproducible example so we can test ourselves.

Comment: seems to be related to how much data is in each string being set into the TreeView columns.  Gtk+ has no problem handling large string (180..300 characters long) where as gtkmm slows exponentially.  Basically, gtkmm is stuffed unless the data is small, and even then (making each string only 3 characters long for 100,000 records) it runs 14x slower than its C counter part.

Comment: Bob - I wrote the minimal code and tried to add it, but kept getting a mal-formatted error and, although I wouldn't mind input, I simply don't have the time to work out StackOverflow's idiosyncracies.  Thank you for your input, though, it led directly to understanding that the problem is the length of each string.

Comment: Oh that's unfortunate. At least you found your answer.